# Confused with the notion of a rank of a group.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I am interested in understanding the ranks of finite groups of Lie Type. Say we have a Suzuki group ${}^2B_2(q)$ with $q$ power of 2 or a Ree group ${}^2G_2(q)$ with $q=3^{2m+1}$. What can be said about their ranks?

Comment: By rank, do you mean Lie rank? I think they both have Lie rank $1$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. I am actually looking for a rank in the context of this paper https://msp.org/pjm/1999/187-2/pjm-v187-n2-p02-s.pdf.    Also, does this rank stay the same for all the groups in the series? I am not sure I understand the notion correctly. Is it related to the minimal number of generators of the group?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the minimal number of generators of the group iteslf, which is 2 for all finite nonabelian simple groups. It is the rank of a maximal torus, and yes it stays the same for groups in the same series. I am not an expert on this topic so I won't attempt to be any more precise!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, your comment was very helpful!